# Converting macro-defined functions to a template in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, macros, member-functions

I'm dealing with the following hard-to-debug code in [a C++ program](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim/blob/3177a7c5a644e9de15e6ed6aa9d3afa84043a230/riscv/mmu.h#L81). I'm very new to C++, but I thought this might be a good candidate for conversion to a template. However, I'm having a hard time understanding what that would look like and how the new functions would be called. Would I still have multiple load_func functions, that would then just call the template function with an explicit type specified? Or could all 8 of these functions be replaced with a single function template? Which approach would be better? I believe that the first approach would require the least modification to other files, while the second would require that I update all calls to these functions to specify the type explicitly.

```
class mmu_t
{
public:
//...
  // template for functions that load an aligned value from memory
  #define load_func(type) \
    inline type##_t load_##type(reg_t addr) { \
      // ... Other code elided for clarity
      type##_t res; \
      load_slow_path(addr, sizeof(type##_t), (uint8_t*)&res); \
      return res; \
    }

  // load value from memory at aligned address; zero extend to register width
  load_func(uint8)
  load_func(uint16)
  load_func(uint32)
  load_func(uint64)

  // load value from memory at aligned address; sign extend to register width
  load_func(int8)
  load_func(int16)
  load_func(int32)
  load_func(int64)
}
```

Comment: Maybe it was just the simplification, but if the functions don't use `this` at all, they should be marked `static`.  (And if all the members of a class are `static`, it shouldn't be a class.)

Comment: @aschepler load_slow_path is a member function that uses non-static member variables. Also I think the code I left out also uses member variables. You check it out in the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky issue here is that the existing code defines 8 functions with 8 different names (`load_uint8`, `load_uint16`, ..., `load_int64`), but a function template only has one name.

So sure, you could change this to

```
template <typename T>
inline T load_integer(reg_t addr) {
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "T must be an integer type");
    // Other code...
    T res;
    load_slow_path(addr, sizeof(T), reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&res));
    return res;
}
```

But if that's all you replace it with, yes, the rest of the code would need to change from `mmu.load_uint8(addr)` to `mmu.load_integer<uint8_t>(addr)` and so on.

So it would probably be a good idea to also supply the old functions for backward compatibility:

```
inline uint8_t load_uint8(reg_t addr) { return load_integer<uint8_t>(addr); }
// ...
```

At that point, have you changed anything but improved the style of that class a bit?  The generated executable code is likely to not be different at all.  You do gain one benefit: now `load_integer<T>` can be called from another template function that operates on more than one type of integer data.

Comment: "At that point, have you changed anything but improved the style of that class a bit?" I'm trying to debug this code base with gdb and stepping through the code. With a template, stepping through the code via `(gdb) next` becomes much easier, right? Right now `next` steps over the whole block.

There are *lots* of places in this code base that seem to be overusing macros like this. Check out the example here: https://github.com/riscv/riscv-fesvr/blob/6330e8668092e8a9c8af97f75313261d8e39b001/fesvr/elfloader.cc#L37

Comment: @EvanCox - Yes, a template is debugable, unlike a macro. So even the forwarding solution will help you manage your code already.

Answer (score 4):

It's very much possible, and pretty straight forward.

1. `##type` becomes the template parameter at the call site, e.g `load<uint8_t>`.
2. The function definition is pretty much the same. Only now the template parameter is a stand in for the type.

   ```
   template<typename T>
   inline T load(reg_t addr) {
     // ... Other code elided for clarity
     T res; 
     load_slow_path(addr, sizeof(T), (uint8_t*)&res); 
     return res; 
   }
   ```

And that's it. No need to do anything else, except adjusting the call sites. But I consider it worth it for the brevity you gained.

If that's too daunting, then you can create the template, and change the macro definition into a simple forwarding function, as you noted in your post.

Only you can weigh the cost against the benefits.

Comment: The type is `type##_t`, not `##type`. The `##` is a binary operator in the preprocessor; `##type` doesn’t even mean anything.

Comment: @DanielH - `type` isn't really a type. It's a token, I know :)

Comment: No, but `type##_t` becomes a token for a type name, while `type` is by itself something like `uint8`, and so not even that.

Comment: @DanielH - Note I explicitly mentioned the call site. The point is turning `load_uint8` into `load<uint8_t>`.

Comment: I understood what StoryTeller meant, the focus here anyways isn't on preprocessor/macro tokenization and concatenation.

Comment: How could this be restricted to just the original 8 types? Would is_integral static assert from other answer work?

Comment: @EvanCox - Restriction is possible in several ways. An assertion is indeed one, and probably the easiest. If one requires SFINAE friendliness, then that can be accomplished with another template parameter. And if one wants to make the function definition private to boot, that's possible too with explicit template instantiations. It all depends on ones needs.

Comment: @StoryTeller thanks. Both very good answers, but the other one is more complete so I picked that one even though you were first. I still really appreciate it!